# use macro to test function return value in C

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I want to have a macro which does something like:

`#define TEST(_ptr) ({ if ((_ptr) == NULL) ERROR; (_ptr); })`

which check `_ptr` and calls `ERROR` macro or return its value.

However, if I use something like `var = TEST(fun())` this results in `fun()` being called two times.

I can do something like:

`#define TEST(_tmp, _ptr) ({ _tmp = _ptr; if ((_tmp) == NULL) ERROR; (_tmp); })`

is there any clean way of doing this without passing temporary storage, e.g. using `typeof` operator!?

Comment: Note that [expression statements](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) are a GCC extension over Standard C, as is the [`typeof`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Typeof.html#Typeof) operator.  It's OK to use them as long as you are aware of the portability issues you are creating.

Comment: What's the problem with using 8 bytes of temporary storage?  Your machine isn't that cramped for memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
/* Assuming your ERROR, something like this */
#define ERROR \
({ \
    printf("Error, Null pointer passed\n"); \
    exit(1); \
})

#define TEST1(_ptr) \
({ \
    typeof(_ptr) _tmp = _ptr; \
    if ((_tmp) == NULL) ERROR; \
    (_tmp); \
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a macro definition, why not use a regular function as in:

```
void *funcCaller (void *f) {
    if (f == NULL) {
        ERROR;    // not sure what the ERROR thing is supposed to do or look like.
    }

    return f;
}
```

Then call it as in:

```
p = funcCaller (func());
```

Since the argument list for `funcCaller()` is using a `void *` then the return type of `func()` could be any pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

By comparing `(_ptr) == NULL` I'm assuming your `func()` returns a pointer.
In this case you can change the `TEST(_ptr)` macro to:

```
#define TEST(_ptr) ({ void* _rt = _ptr; if ((_rt) == NULL) ERROR; (_rt); })
```